# Sorting an array with child - parent dependencies

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am given the following array of objects:

```
let data = [{id: 3, name: ''}, {id: 4, name: ''}, {id: 5, name: '', parent: 3}, {id: 6, name: '', parent: 5},   {id: 7, name: '', parent: 4}, {id: 8, name: '', parent: 8}];
```

How do I create a nested list, where an object with corresponding parent element is appended to a new `<li>` element? So to make it clear it would look something like this:

```
<li>
  object id:3 (parent)
    <li>object id:5</li>(child)
</li>`
```

Any clues? :)

Comment: This sounds like grouping, not sorting.

Comment: @Edit, Got the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with two functions one to create nested tree structure and another one to create a nested html structure based on previously create tree structure.

```js
let data = [{id: 3, name: ''}, {id: 4, name: ''}, {id: 5, name: '', parent: 3}, {id: 6, name: '', parent: 5},   {id: 7, name: '', parent: 4}, {id: 8, name: '', parent: 8}];

const toTree = (data, pid = undefined) => {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (pid == e.parent) {
      const obj = { ...e }
      const children = toTree(data, e.id);
      if (children) obj.children = children
      r.push(obj)
    }

    return r
  }, [])
}

const toHtml = (data) => {
  const ul = document.createElement('ul')

  data.forEach(e => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const text = document.createElement('span')

    text.textContent = `object id: ${e.id}`;
    li.appendChild(text)

    const children = toHtml(e.children);
    if (children) li.appendChild(children)

    ul.appendChild(li)
  })

  return ul
}

const tree = toTree(data)
const html = toHtml(tree)

document.body.appendChild(html)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, it does work just fine. Initially I planned to do something similar with double for loops and make a separate array with all elements sorted. Do you have an idea how to solve this using vue.js? I'm not sure whether there's a way to do it by communicating between different templates/components

Comment: I haven't worked with vue.js but you would probably just modify `toHtml` function and replace plain js method to create elements with vue.